# Does JSON.parse() use eval() internally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, ecmascript-5

Does `JSON.parse` in modern browsers use `eval()` internally for evaluating and executing the dynamic code?

Because I have been looking through Douglas Crockford's JSON library. It also uses `eval()` when using parse() but after preprocessing prior to the actual evaluation. Such as:-

1. A wall against Unicode characters in the code.
2. A code shows malicious intent.

Do the modern browsers which supports JSON.parse natively perform this or they follow other protocols?

Comment: @dystroy i'm intrigued now - where's the source?

Comment: Please check here

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Line no. 471

Comment: @sircapsalot In fact, there is more than one implementation by Crockord. Here's [one without eval](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js).

Comment: There's no reason for browsers to internally use `eval`, so I'm sure they don't use it. It's easy to port or change `json_parse.js` (I did it).

Comment: A proof at least IE doesn't use eval is that on IE9 `eval('('+json+')')` crashes the browser on big JSON strings while `JSON.parse` doesn't crash :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No, `JSON.parse()` doesn't Use `eval()`

This is by design, as `eval()` being able to execute any arbitrary JavaScript code you feed it, it could execute things you wouldn't want it to. So `JSON.parse()` does what it says on the tin: it actually parses the whole string and reconstructs and entire object tree.

`JSON.parse` is usually delegated to an internal function implemented with "native" code,  where "native" means whatever is considered "native" in the context of your browser's javascript engine (could be compiled machine code, could be bytecode for a VM, etc...).  I don't think there's any strong requirement on that.

## Differences in the Implementations?

JSON (the notation) itself is codified by the [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Regarding the implemetation of the `JSON` object and its methods, all **modern** browsers implementing should behave the same, as they should follow the same specifications for [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1)'s [JSON object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12). However, there's always the chance for potential defects. For instance, V8 originally contained this [nasty bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=372).

Also, note that the implementation listed in comments above are for you to add `JSON.parse()` support to browsers that do not support it natively (also known as "these damn old browsers you sometimes need to support"). But it doesn't mean that it's necessarily how they implemented it.

For instance, for Google's V8 implementation used in Chrome, see  [json.js](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/json.js) which invokes native code from [json_parser.h](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/json-parser.h).

Answer (score -1):

It would be a very funny thing to do, if you think about it.

To understand why, see if this analogy helps: you're traveling with your boss to a country where you speak the language but she doesn't. Since you're fluent, you will serve two roles: as her assistant (doing tasks for her) as well as her translator (telling her what things mean).

So you have these two jobs, which are complementary. Your boss could tell you to do something--in any language you both understand (say, English)--as well as ask you to tell her what something says, like a sign or a document. She could even do both: hand you a set of instructions written in this other language and say, "This was given to me by someone I trust. Please do everything it says here."

In this analogy, reading signs or documents to your boss is like `JSON.parse`. Your boss handing you instructions and telling you to do everything they say is like `eval`.

If JavaScript engines used `eval` internally for `JSON.parse`, that would be analogous to your boss asking you what a document says, and you choosing to *act out* everything written in the document in order to explain it to her. Instead of just reading it.